# Type hint for argument of type A in method of class A

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make use of type hints in Python 3.5.1 with following code:

```
>>> class A:                         
...     def a(self, i: int, b: A):   
...         pass                     
...                                  
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in A       
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

I guess it's problem with scoping that type A is not yet fully constructed while parsing type A, but I fail to understand why such a syntax is not OK. Is there some way to express it otherwise or it's simply illegal construct?

I wanted to use this syntax hint in base class that could compose derived classes in tree-like hierarchy.

Comment: Look in to using decorators for this type of thing, or Metaclasses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
class A:

    def a(self, i: int, b: 'A'):
        pass
```

For more information take a look [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references)